# Retag without privilege

Tags: support, status-bydesign, tags, privileges

Hello,
I'm able to retag a question and therefore earn the organizer badge even if I have less than 500 reputation.

Comment: Everybody can edit, so I think that is an expected issue.

Comment: Then the privilege is useless ;)

Comment: The privilege lets you do it without needing to go through the approval process.

Comment: ooh, that's it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The retag privilege itself gives you the ability to retag questions without needing the approval of others. It adds a "retag" link next to the edit link that will allow you to edit *only* the tags, thus bypassing the whole suggested edit process. Clicking the edit button instead will take you to the normal editing screen where retags *can* still be made, but approval will still be required when assisted with other edits.

Note that while you have the retag privilege without full editing privileges, you cannot make a tag-only edit from the main edit screen. You *must* use the separate retag functionality.