# Why is the retag disabled for me even though I have reputation to do this?

Tags: support, tags, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why did the “retag” link disappear underneath questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125120/why-did-the-retag-link-disappear-underneath-questions)

The retag feature is disabled for me:

> [image]

Now as in the question [retag without privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84590/retag-without-privilege), in the moderator [Grace Note ⋄](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146126/grace-note)'s comment, he said that if a user has enough reputation (I have 2.4k), the user can edit without approval so why is the retag disabled for me? Even I have not retagged yet for the last 24 hours.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why did the "retag" link disappear underneath questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125120/why-did-the-retag-link-disappear-underneath-questions) and [What is the reason for removing the retag link for users with full editing rights?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88151/what-is-the-reason-for-removing-the-retag-link-for-users-with-full-editing-right)

Comment: @animuson sorry i tried but i have not got anything before asking ...and now i can neither delete the question(have answer) nor close the question (havnt got option )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your reputation is between 500 and 2000, you will see a "retag" link. If you have more than 2000 reputation, you can retag using the "edit" link instead. You can edit the question to retag it.

Comment: The OP has more than 2k on SO.

Comment: @Mysticial Yes, that's why he don't see `retag` because he can retag using `edit` button.