# Retag question reputation required = 500?

Tags: support, tags, edits, privileges

While editing the questions I have been adding tags for quite some time now.
As proof I have the **Organizer** badge which is awarded for first retag.
Yet I am able to do so with a reputation under 500. Why?

Comment: See: [Retag without privilege](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84590/retag-without-privilege).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You require 500 reputation to retag question](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions). You earned *organizer* badge by suggesting retag not by direct retagging.